# AFNetworking Rest API with Etag Caching

Tags: json, caching, afnetworking, etag, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to implement etag caching in a GET request I send using AFNetworking, but I can't seem to find a solution out there that has AFNetworking REST API ~AND~ caching. Need example  code that shows how to send GET/POST and control the cache. What I have right now is just the request, not cache:

```
NSString *path = @"path/to/my.json";
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:self.baseNSURL];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[client getPath:path
     parameters:nil
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
        }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
 ];
```

and the outgoing HEADER (no cache control):

GET path/to/my.json HTTP/1.1
Host: x.y.com:80
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json
Cookie: PHPSESSID=35gojgf7s35n8fljlvd5pjudfn0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en, fr, de, ja, nl, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, sv, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us;q=0.8
User-Agent: myApp/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.1; Scale/1.00)
X-Forwarded-For: 192.130.1.00

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking just follows the NSURLRequest / NSURLCache rules.  So, you need to add cache control headers to cache to disk that way.  You can also use (or modify) [SDURLCache](https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache) if you want more manual control over the disk caching.

Comment: Can you show some code? Also, do I need to use core data to save the response for each etag, or it is taken care of?

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-network-caching-http-headers - you don't need to put anything in core data, just make sure your HTTP headers are set correctly both ways.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have implemented the NSURLCache in my app delegate like the tutorial said. But I still don't get etag in my response header. I know that the server gives an etag. Do I need to place something in my request header? If so what? a line of code is so much more helpful that a link! Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the server gives an etag if it's not in your response header?

Comment: ok, after a long night we realized that the Rest tool we were using was getting the etag, but for some reason, when we use the phone, the server did not. And we suspect that it is because the server is GZiping the the data, and in our setup, that prevented etag. Turing off gzip makes it come through. But still need to get the code to wrok with that change. I'll let you know in a few days if we got it to work.

Comment: @MehdiAbderezai You should check out https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger - this tool will log stuff to your console in Xcode and can be easily modified to show any information you need